# Efficiently Set Lowest 64 Bits of YMM Register to Constant

Tags: optimization, assembly, sse, vectorization, avx

How can I set the lowest 64 bits of a YMM register to some constant, in the least number of clock cycles? I know various ways that I can do this using SSE instructions, as well as the AVX instruction `VBROADCASTSD`, but I'm not sure which method will yield the best result.

Edit: I still need to use the complete YMM register after setting the 64-bit part.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Depends if you want to use the complete YMM register after setting the low 64 bit or only the XMM part.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity -- I need to use the complete YMM register after setting the low 64 bit.

Comment: It also depends on the constant. Some constant values can be generated easily, others have to be loaded from memory)

Comment: That's definitely true. Such a seemingly simple question requires a lot of specifications! The constants I am trying to load have no easily reproducible pattern (at least by using a small number of bitwise, arithmetic, broadcast, or permutation operations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need to set lowest 64 bits and other YMM bits do not matter, use `VMOVQ`.

If you need to preserve other bits in YMM register, the most efficient way is to use `VBLENDPD`. Alternatively, you can clear the lowest 64 bits with `VANDPD`, then load the constant with `VORPD`.

AVX2 allows other alternatives to do it: `VPMASKMOVD` or `VPBLENDD` (but it is not yet supported by any processor).

Comment: I can also suggest VBLENDPD (latency 1 on Sandy Bridge) instead of VANDPD+VORPD.

Comment: @NorbertP. VBLENDPD is definitely better. Thanks.